# how to spyon angular.extend function in jasmine?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, spyon

My code is as below:

```
angular.extend($scope, {
    refreshQueries: function() {
        //code to refresh the tab.......
    },
    queriesTab: {
       tab: 'queryTab',
       refreshFunc: $scope.refreshQueries,
       refreshInterval: 5
    }
 });
```

I want to check using jasmine whether I am able to switch the tab or not.. Basically wanted to spyon 'refreshFunc' of queriesTab tab.. How can I do that?

Not able to to spyon using below syntax in jasmine test case.`var queriesFunc = spyOn(scope.queriesTab,'refreshFunc');`

Comment: `angular.extend` is an utility function, I am not sure that you should test how it was called, but the result of that call. What error do you get when creating a spy?